# Parameterizing $f(x, y) = z$ then what does $f(x(t), y(t)) = z$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Let's say we have a function $f(x, y) = z$ and we parameterize it as follows: 
$$\{x(t), y(t)\} = \{0.1, 2\} + t \nabla f(0.1, 2)$$
$$f(x(t), y(t)) = z$$
As I understand it, we've essentially transformed it into a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, which has the highest intitial ($t = 0$) $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ of all possible parameterizations at the point $\{0.1, 2, f(0.1, 2)\}$. So if we graph this parameterized $f$, what will it represent?

Comment: $z = f(x,y)$ represents a 2-dimensional surface. The parameterization $(x(t), \, y(t), f(x(t),y(t)))$ defines a 1-dimensional curve on that surface, with the property that at the point $(0.1,2)$, the curve is moving in the direction of greatest increase.